# Extract specific words from cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need to extract a word that has the first letter as a capital B and a word length of 10 digits from an Excel sheet.

[image]

Example: if cell `A1` contains "ASIN [ASIN is erroneously marked as ASIN: B07VYZC00H, the value is null but B010976527." So in this sentence or a paragraph I need to extract "B07VYZC00H" and "B010976527".

Comment: You need to be using the `right()` function, passing in 10 as your number of characters to extract. Something like `strASIN = right(A1,10)`

Comment: Okay so suppose, the cell is A1 and from their i need to extract all the words that starts with B and have 10 characters then what formula we can use? I am bad in excel, if you can help me out in writing the formula it will be really great.

Comment: Would/could cell A1 contain something like "B123456789, ASIN: B234567890, B987654321"? Or does each cell contain one 10 character string, sometimes containing an "ASIN" prefix?

Comment: Sometimes it can have Asin but most of the time a cell can have B123456789, B987654321.

Comment: I need to fetch all the words from cell that starts with B and are of 10 characters. There is no suffix or prefix is fixed.

Comment: If a cell can contain multiple ASIN's, then I would suggest using a `for` `next` loop and the `instr()` function to pull out your values. See if you can figure it out with those pointers...

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use that

Comment: I'm not going to write it for you, as I don't know what the data look like, but here are some pointers. `Dim` an `int` to keep track of your loop. In your `for` `next` loop, use the `instr` function to search the string for your value, and be sure to increment the value of the declared integer. There are plenty of Microsoft docs articles on these functions. Give it a go, and then update your question with where you're stuck.

Comment: Create simple VBA function which performs this task.

Comment: I've removed the excel version tags as multiple were being used at the same time. If this is version-specific please only tag the version in question.

Comment: If you need all the results in a single cell, comma-separated, it would be easiest with VBA or Power Query.  If you have Excel 2016, you could do it with formulas.  If the results can be in separate cells in the same row, then you could use formulas in any version.